# RegEx javascript text file

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an textfile with this structure:

```
06-05-13 21:52:10: Wence: Hey how you're doing?

10-05-13 16:14:49: Wence: Everythings okay over here

10-05-13 16:14:52: Wence: Nevermind, I just spoke to your mom and she told me you are fine.

10-05-13 16:14:58: Wence: I'll host the bbq tonight. Would be fun if you came.
```

From this large string, I need to read the date, time, and message, but I need it in a key/value pair like this:

```
var message = {"Wence": "Hey how you're doing?", "Wence": "Everythings okay over here"}
var time = {"Wence": "16:14:52", "Wence": "16:14:49"}
var date = {"Wence": "10-05-13", "Wence": "10-05-13"}
```

I am using these RegEx patterns to find the message, date and time:

```
Date: /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/
Time: /(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/
Name: /[A-z][0-9]\:/
Message: (need to figure this out, don't know how to search for a string between patterns)
```

Strangely enough, when I'm trying to split these regex function like

```
var date = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/; 
var dates = chat.split(date);
```

It doens't split the date in a way that I can save it in an Array.

I splits it like "xx","xx","xx","rest of string","xx","xx","xx

Any help on how to solve this problem and how to parse the message is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try parsing the entire line:

```
var regex = /(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d): ([^:]+): (.*)/g;
var messages = [];
var match;
while( match = regex.exec(chat)) {
    messages.push({
        date: match[1],
        time: match[2],
        name: match[3],
        message: match[4]
    });
}
```

Comment: Please don't Doge-compliment me again XD